# Installing Lubuntu: manual partitioning does not work

Tags: partitioning, lubuntu, documentation

I'm trying to install Lubuntu on my laptop* from a USB, using the lubuntu-20.10-desktop-amd64.iso file downloaded from the (I believe) Chip website because the file at the Lubuntu website didn't load. When it comes to "Partitions", I get the choice to

- erase the disk [which I have already done using DBAN, so it's not necessary; besides, it took three attempts with DBAN, the third taking > 48 hours when it was eventually successful... so I'd rather not erase again when it's not necessary]
- Manual partitioning
  [no other options]
  Well, so I chose manual partitioning and would've liked to do it according to this page: http://www.control-escape.com/linux/lx-partition.html ... but I don't seem to be able to do that. First I need to set up a "new partition table" (choosing between MBR and GPT - one step before, Lubuntu recommended GPT, is that true also for this choice??)...
  ... and then a "New Volume Group" - see the [attached picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HlPIx.jpg) for the dialog box. There I can enter a "Volume Group Name" and a "Physical Extent Size" of up to 999 MiB (no GiB!). 999 MiB seems not very big... and most of all, I can never click "OK" (it remains inactive).

What am I doing wrong? How can I proceed the installation?
Thanks a lot in advance!!!!!

*My laptop has supposedly 500GB, the installation walk-through says 465,8 GiB. Dual-Core 4GB.

*** Sorry, I haven't found how to respond to your comments 1-3 specifically, so I'm editing my replies here. :-( ***

Thanks for your replies. I have now re-downloaded the Lubuntu image, this time: lubuntu-20.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso (from the lubuntu.me URL). I used the browser download because I'm using someone else's computer and would prefer not to install a bittorrent client there. Although I failed verifying the file (I'm using a Windows 10 computer, but apparently I need another program for verifying?...), I tentatively proceeded and started installing Lubuntu. Well, I then received an error message posted here[enter link description here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1321909/installation-of-lubuntu-20-04-failed-non-zero-exit-status-32) ... but at least it seems I got around the manual partitioning issue.

Thanks!

Comment: I'd start by going back and downloading the file from the right source: https://lubuntu.me and then verifying the .iso as described.

Comment: Please provide details about your Lubuntu web site.   Did you use google to find it (you'll find it offers 3 sites for download of Lubuntu, and only one is legitimate and affiliated with Lubuntu/Ubuntu).  If you're unsure of which is official, you're best going to ubuntu.com and looking there, ie. https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours will take you to the official site for any Ubuntu flavor.  My guess (like KGIII) is you went to a 3rd party/fake site and not a Lubuntu site.

Comment: Erase disk means create a new partition table (the use of `dban` does something different, far beyond the creation of a partition table).   I'd suggest following the Lubuntu manual, ie. https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/1/Installing_lubuntu.html and official documentation

Comment: To verify the file using windows; refer https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0  (it covers Ubuntu & Mac OS directly; with a link for windows).

Answer (score -1):

I ended up formatting the hard drive. (Thanks for the comments!)

BTW, when I realized that my USB stick (boot drive) was formatted in exFAT and reformatted it to NTFS, I received the full 4-point menu instead of just formatting or manual partitioning. Nonetheless, I decided to format the hard drive.