# Installation of Lubuntu 20.04 failed: “non-zero exit status 32”

Tags: software-installation, lubuntu, 32-bit

I had first posted this as an extension of [an unrelated question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1321686/installing-lubuntu-manual-partitioning-does-not-work-installation-failed-no), but I guess it makes more sense to start its own thread here. I have tried to install lubuntu-20.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso (downloaded from the lubuntu.me URL). I soon received the following error message:

```
Installation Failed
Boost.Python error in job "unpackfs".
Command 'mount' returned non-zero exit status 32.

None. Traceback: File "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/calamares/modules/unpackfs/main.py", line 423, in run return unpackop.run()
 File "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/calamares/modules/unpackfs/main.py", line 241, in run return unpackop.run()
 File "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/calamares/modules/unpackfs/main.py", line 302, in run return unpackop.run()
[X Close]
```

Do you have any suggestions about how to resolve this issue? I'm not sure this has anything to do with [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/calamares/+bug/1873950), and even so I'm not sure how to work around it.

Unfortunately, I had not managed to verify the iso file before installing. (I'm using a Windows 10 computer, but apparently I need another program for verifying? At least in the regular command line, "gpg" or "sha256sum" are not recognized as valid commands. Do you have any suggestions where I can read up on how to use those commands?) A first web search did not help, so I tentatively proceeded and tried burning to USB, booting and installing. If you should think that my failure to verify ties into the problem: How can I read up on verifying / using "gpg" and "sha256sum" / ...?

Comment: Please clarify a few things.. You've tagged 32-bit, however only an *amd64* image is available for Lubuntu 20.04 LTS mentioned in your title (i386 or 32-bit was available for 18.04, 18.10 & 19.04 *alpha*).  Your paste messages are also for *amd64* (64-bit)

Comment: I'll point you to a solution found for another user who had this issue; (with 19.04)  https://discourse.lubuntu.me/t/noob-problem-installing/209/28 which will lead you back to this site anyway

Comment: Does this answer your question? [eMMC Boot - Installation & Compatibility](https://askubuntu.com/questions/879986/emmc-boot-installation-compatibility)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my USB stick was formatted to exFAT. When I used NTFS, everything worked out and I am now writing this from my own computer on Linux. Hooray! :-)

[Sorry for the late reply, I was sick and for some days didn't get to anyone's computer... at least at the end of the time I suddenly got the idea about NTFS.

Oh, and askubuntu seems to have added "32-bit" - I had just meant to tag "zero exit status 32", which apparently went completely wrong...]

Nonetheless thanks a lot for your comments!!

Answer (score -1):

I had exactly same error. None of tips suggested here didnt work. I found out later issue was with selected format of image in Rufus. It should be DD, not ISO. Now it works fine.